# Paste a value from a drop-down list

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I am creating a macro that creates a new sheet inside my excel file, and I need that the sheet has the same same as the chosen place from the drop-down box.[image]

When you click Button 1, a new sheet appears but I don't know how to name is the same as the selected name. This is my code so far:

[image]

I need to replace "newname" with the health autority selected from the drop-down box.

As you can see the name is already stored, as I copied it. I was thinking that the solution may be using a paste spacial-value, but i don't know how to write it.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("user").Range("M42").Value`

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("User")).Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("User")Range("M42").Value` but you'll get an error if there's already a sheet with that name.

Comment: Do you know how to paste in the new sheet just the data for a chosen health authority? Inside my data there is a column of health authorities and each one has a number assigned to it so depending on the number the person is from that health authority.

Comment: Please avoid pasting code as an image. type "``` VBA" then on the next line paste all your code then end with "```"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is an existing sheet with the new name before adding to avoid the subsequent error.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub createsheet()

   Dim sName As String, ws As Worksheet
   sName = Sheets("user").Range("M42").Value
   
   ' check if already exists
   On Error Resume Next
   Set ws = Sheets(sName)
   On Error GoTo 0
   
   If ws Is Nothing Then
       ' ok add
       Set ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
       ws.Name = sName
       MsgBox "Sheet created : " & ws.Name, vbInformation
   Else
       ' exists
       MsgBox "Sheet '" & sName & "' already exists", vbCritical, "Error"
   End If
   
End Sub
```

Comment: I have already sorted it by putting .value to the cell containing the name. Shall I put this as a new macro?

Comment: @andrea No this replaces completely your macro.